# Postman Request Scripting: Extracting Values From Response And Setting Global Variable Values

Tags: javascript, scripting, postman, global-variables, response-headers

I am writing a pre-request script in Postman which is meant to set the value of a global variable, API_TOKEN.

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_URL"),
    method: "GET",
    header: {
        clientId: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_CLIENT_ID"),
        clientSecret: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_CLIENT_SECRET")
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.header)
    pm.globals.set("API_TOKEN", response.header[3].apitoken)
})
```

My issue is that `console.log(response.header)` logs `undefined`, even though `console.log(response)` logs an object with various fields just fine:

```
{
    id: ...
    status: ...
    code: ...
    header: [11]
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick was to access `response.headers.all()[3].value` instead of `response.header[3].value`.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_URL"),
    method: "GET",
    header: {
        clientId: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_CLIENT_ID"),
        clientSecret: pm.globals.get("GET_API_TOKEN_CLIENT_SECRET")
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    console.log(error ? error : response)
    if (error) {
        return
    } else {
        pm.globals.set("API_TOKEN", response.headers.all()[3].value)
    }
})
```